# Is there a way that I can upgrade my glib in opensuse 13.1?

Tags: opensuse, glib

I am trying to install gtk+ but this requires glib >= 2.39 and I have 2.38. I would like to upgrade to 2.40 but once I installed it it still told me it could not find it. Now I could not change the path but that does not seem very elegant.

Can I just upgrade, or if not can you please give me a clear instruction as to how I can change my path?

My opensuse is divided in two partitions and the lib is in the `/home` partition (At least his is how I understand it, this is my first time with Linux).